# ubuntu server crashes on startup while loading/saving backlight brightness

Tags: server, 18.04, crash

Right after installing Ubuntu server, it starts ok and I can use it. But after the first reboot it just freezes. The cursor even stops blinking

The last line is screen is

```
 Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of leds:dell::kbd_backlight...
```

Before that I see

```
Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0...
[ OK ] Started Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video0.
```

If I boot in recovery it still stops there but the cursor keeps blinking

I kind of had the same issue with centos but I cloud not see the terminal so I don't know if it was in this step.

This machine has run non server Linux distros before
(Lubuntu for example)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on LXLE which is an Ubuntu flavor of the LTS desktop version 16.04.4 which I was trying to run on an Inspiron 1018 which has no keyboard backlighting.

Did you get this problem figured out?  Did some research & found the answer at the Linux Lite forum.

Go directly into recovery mode only stopping long enough to hit the <kbd>e</kbd> & change the file system to `rw` from `ro`.
At the recovery menu select `root` & then enter to get to the prompt.
Being a novice I went to the `/var/lib/systemd/backlight` folder to look at the `platform-dell-laptop:leds:dell::kbd_backlight` file when actually I think all I would have had to do was `systemctl mask systemd-backlight@leds\:dell\:\:kbd_backlight.service`.

That fixed the problem & I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Somehow disabling this backlight thing worked like a charm. Could you please explain what you did there.

Comment: I’m having the same problem in Xubuntu, Lubuntu, and Bunsen Helium on a Dell Inspiron Mini 1012. After working for a day or so, a reboot fails. In all instances, it’s the backlight error. I don’t have anything in the backlight folder though.